# Resolve into factors $\dfrac{a^3}{x^2}-8x-a^3+8x^3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Resolve into factors $\dfrac{a^3}{x^2}-8x-a^3+8x^3$

$\Rightarrow (\dfrac{a^3}{x^2}-8x)+8x^3-a^3$

$\Rightarrow x(\dfrac{a^3}{x^3}-8)+8x^3-a^3$

$\Rightarrow x[(\dfrac{a}{x})^3-2^3]+(2x)^3-a^3$

$\Rightarrow x[(\dfrac{a}{x}-2)(\dfrac{a^2}{x^2}+\dfrac{2a}{x}+4)]+(2x-a)(4x^2+2ax+a^2)$

$\Rightarrow (a-2x)(\dfrac{a^2}{x}+2a+4x)-(a-2x)(4x^2+2ax+a^2)$

$\Rightarrow (a-2x)(\dfrac{a^2}{x}+2a+4x-4x^2-2ax-a^2)$

$\Rightarrow (a-2x)[(\dfrac{a^2}{x}-a^2)+(2a-2ax)+(4x-4x^2)]$

$\Rightarrow (a-2x)[a^2(\dfrac{1}{x}-1)+2a(1-x)+4x(1-x)]$

$\Rightarrow (a-2x)[a^2(\dfrac{1}{x}-1)+(2a+4x)(1-x)]$

$\Rightarrow (a-2x)[a^2(\dfrac{1}{x}-1)+2(a+2x)(1-x)]$

Then I'm stuck. But I am not sure if the $x$ should be multiplied to both terms in the parenthesis or just one of them (in the 4th line). Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: In your last line, notice that $1/x -1 = (1-x)/x$ so you can factor out the $(1-x)$ in your second factor.

Comment: Hint :  $$p(x)=(x-1)(x+1)Q(x)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

$$\frac{1}{x^2}(a^3-8x^3-a^3x^2+8x^5)$$

$$=\frac{1}{x^2}(a^3(1-x^2) - 8x^3(1-x^2))$$

$$=\frac{1}{x^2}(1-x^2)(a^3-8x^3)$$

$$=\frac{1}{x^2}(1-x)(1+x)(a-2x)(a^2+2ax+4x^2).$$

Comment: It should be +2ax not -2ax in the last line

Answer (score 0):

Let : $$p(x)=\frac {a^3}{x^2}-8x－a^3＋8x^3$$

You can see: $$p(1)=p(-1)=0$$
$$\implies p(x)=(x-1)(x+1)Q(x)$$

$$\implies Q(x)=\frac{p(x)}{x^2-1}$$

**using [Ruffini's rule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruffini%27s_rule)**

$$\implies Q(x)=8x－\frac {a^3}{x^2}$$

**Finally :**
$$\frac {a^3}{x^2}-8x－a^3＋8x^3=(x-1)(x+1)(8x－\frac {a^3}{x^2})$$